# Can someone please explain user-defined comparisons? c++

Tags: c++

I am having trouble understanding the following code. I understand the concept of a user-defined comparison is to sort an object in a certain way, but I don't understand how this code works.

```
struct P {
    int x, y;
    bool operator<(const P &p) {
        if (x != p.x) return x < p.x;
        else return y < p.y;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can you give more details about which parts of this code you don't understand? It might help to come up with some specific values of `P` and step through the lines to see how the comparison works.

Comment: Is this a "lazy" (skipping trig functions) distance comparison function? It does not look like a "perfect" comparison. What are you comparing?

Comment: @TedLyngmo What do you mean by "lazy" and "perfect"? Is there any indication that distance is relevant at all here? Couldn't "x" and "y" just be "section" and "sub-section"?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Indeed, they could. I asked because of a hunch.

Comment: The code simply says to sort by x unless both values of x are the same, in which case sort by y. Think of sorting by two columns, the first column sorts, and then where there are duplicates in the first column it sorts by the second column.

Comment: In any case, u don't need this `else`

Comment: @TedLyngmo This looks like a lexicographic sort, I don't see what it has to do with distance at all.

Comment: @NathanPierson You are probably correct. It wouldn't hurt to make the intent obvious though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ compiler doesn't know what to do when you compare one instance of P with another instance so you have to define the operator in order to use it.

The boolean function for `<` is to return True if the current object is smaller than the other object (p). What "smaller than" means is up for you to decide. The code that you have will return that the current object is smaller than p if it's `x` value is smaller than p's `x` value. If the x values are the same, then it considers if the respective y values are smaller. `x > p.x` by itself is a boolean expression so the function will return if that's true of not.

Let's make a struct for an int for this to be more understandable:

```
struct our_int{
    int x;
    bool operator<(const our_int &p) {
        return x < p; 
    }
};
```